# How do I run a SQL script in CockroachDB inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, cockroachdb

I started a CockroachDB container with the following:

```
docker run -d --name=node1 --hostname=node1 \
--network=db -p 26257:26257 -p 8080:8080 \
-v "${PWD}/sql:/cockroach/sql" \
-v "${PWD}/cockroach-data/node1:/cockroach/cockroach-data" \ 
cockroachdb/cockroach:v2.0.1 start --insecure
```

The `/sql` directory has `init.sql`, which is a SQL script I want the database to run, this is the command I'm trying to run:

```
docker exec node1 \
"/cockroach/cockroach sql --insecure < /cockroach/sql/init.sql"
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348:
starting container process caused
"exec: \"/cockroach/cockroach sql --insecure < /cockroach/sql/init.sql\":
stat /cockroach/cockroach sql --insecure < /cockroach/sql/init.sql:
no such file or directory": unknown
```

However, if I `docker exec -ti node1 /bin/bash` and run the same command manually, it works.

How can I run `cockroach sql --insecure < [my SQL script]` from outside the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [exec documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description):

> COMMAND should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will
>   not work.
>
> Example: `docker exec -ti my_container "echo a && echo b"`
>   will not work, but `docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b"` will.

You should try:

```
docker exec -ti node1 \
sh -c "/cockroach/cockroach sql --insecure < /cockroach/sql/init.sql"
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for pointing out the documentation. I totally missed the one caveat the command has.